# Connect to Oracle using PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle database which is not on my PC. I have installed Xampp, PHP and Oracle instant Client. I have added a windows environmental path to C:\instantclient_11_1. The Oci8 is enabled too when I check from phpinfo().  I have added the extension extension_dir = C:\php-5.4.0\ext to the php.ini and also enabled extension=php_oci8_11g.dll. Then when I try to connect to the database using the code below:

```
 <?php
 $conn = oci_connect('username', 'password');
 $query = 'select table_name from user_tables';
  ?>
```

It says Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error. Could anyone help?

Comment: You haven't provided a [`connection_string` argument](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php); do you have your environment variables set as described in the documentation, if you are intentionally not providing that?

Comment: which environmental variables you mean? And how am I supposed to set them? If you mean Oracle_Home and TNS I read that these do not need to be set as I am using Oracle instant client..

Comment: OK, if you don't want to use TNS (by which I assume you mean `TNS_ADMIN` and a `tnsnames.ora` file) you'll have to supply the `connection_string` argument, and easy connect is simplest. Did you look at the documentation? How does PHP know which database to connect to and how to reach it if you don't tell it?

Comment: Ok I tried using easy connect by putting $conn = oci_connect('username', 'password', "//localhost/Orcl");
and now it says Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: You said the database is not on your PC, so `localhost` won't be appropriate. What is the server name or IP address of wherever the database is, and what port is its listener running on? And what is the service name of the database - is it actually `orcl` or did you copy that from an example?

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance. How can I know all these details from the Oracle installation directory or sql developer?

Answer (score 3):

The [`oci_connect` call has an optional third parameter for the `connection_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php). As you aren't specifying `TWO_TASK` or `LOCAL` in your environment, as mentioned in the documentation, you have to provide that connection string so that PHP knows how to find and connect to your database.

The general pattern for easy connect syntax is:

```
$conn = oci_connect('username', 'password', '//hostname:port/service_name');
```

Where `hostname` is the name or IP address of the server the database is on - which will *not* be `localhost` since you said it is not on your PC; `port` is the listener port, which defaults to 1521 but could be something else (you can do `lsnrctl status` on the server to check); and `service_name` is the database service name, which may or may not be the same as the SID (you can do `lsnrctl services` to see the valid values on your server).

If you have an SQL Developer connection to the same database, the hostname and port will be shown in the connection settings. It may also show the service name, or may show the SID depending on how it was configured. The service name and SID might be the same. (If you can't run `lsnrctl` but have sufficient privileges you can try `select value from v$parameter where name = 'service_names'`, but it's likely you won't be able to see that view).

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful. I think I managed to find the necessary info. However, now when I try to connect it says Warning: oci_pconnect(): ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

Comment: If you can connect from SQL Developer on the same PC then you must have something different in your PHP connect string to what you use in SQL Developer; wrong host name/IP (maybe a typo?) or port number. I guess it's possible you have a firewall on your PC that's blocking the connection from PHP and allowing the other one but a typo might be more likely.

Comment: No, I can access the SQL Developer and Oracle from a different PC (not mine through RDP) but I am trying to connect to Oracle via PHP from my PC where there's no Oracle and sql developer installed.

Comment: Are you at least on the same network as the DB server then? If you are then it looks like a firewall restriction and you'll need to talk to the network people to get access. If you are not then you might not be able to do this at all, or you might have to use a different hostname/IP, or use a VPN. Again you should probably talk to the network people and tell them what you're trying to do, and see how they recommend (or insist) you do this.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will ask the administrator to allow firewall exception on port 1521 and see how it goes. Thanks for your help.